# Import COM object into COM+ application while retaining access to the COM object directly?

Tags: windows, testing, com, vbscript, com+

I have created a COM+ application using the Component Services MSC dialogs. I imported an existing COM object into this new COM+ application.

I know that it is possible to call that COM object through the COM+ application. I could simply call the COM object as if the COM+ application never existed and it works fine.

My question though, is can I now call the COM object directly? Without going through that COM+ application?

The whole story is that I am using the COM+ application as a wrapper around the 64-bit COM object. Doing it this way allows my 32-bit VBscript code to access the 64-bit COM object. But, this prevents my 32-bit VBscript code from accessing another, identically named, 32-bit COM object as well.

I'd like to maintain access to the 32-bit COM object so that I can test the two different styles (32-bit COM, and 64-bit COM) from one machine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can control which version of code will be loaded via [CLSCTX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693716%28VS.85%29.aspx) enumeration value passed into `CoCreateInstance()` - look at `CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER` and `CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER` values. Not sure how to do that in VBScript.